# Custom filter for table from two different calls

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js, axios

My current situation is that I make 2 get calls via Axios and I receive two different files. First call is complete json file that builds the table and second is only categories (Why? Complicated app is complicated. It is slowly getting upgraded from old framework). I create two dropdowns - first one is populated with years which also builds the table. Second dropdown is populated with categories. When application loads, table is loaded for current year.

My question: How should I create my custom computed filter that would filter the table and show only rows with the selected category(from the second dropdown). So If I select 2019 from first dropdown all the tables are loaded. And after that if I select let's say "Name" in category dropdown, table updates and shows only rows which have "Name" in them. I tried different options but I cannot wrap my head around this one.

My current code:

```
data() {
 return {
  year:[],
  category:[] ,
  tableData:[],
 }
},

computed: {
 axiosParams(){
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('year', this.year);
  return params;
 },

methods: {
 getYears: function(){  
  axios.get('myUrl', {
    params: this.axiosParams
     }).then((response) => {
    this.year = response.data;
    console.log(response.data)   
    this.tableData = response.data.result;
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 },

 getCategory: function(){
   let category = [];
   axios.get('mySecondUrl').then((response, i) => {
    this.category = response.data
    for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
     let catType = i
     this.catType = response.data[i].name;
     console.log(catType);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
 }
}
created: {
 this.getYears();
 this.getCategory();
}
```

My HTML:

```
<select v-model="selectedYear" @change="yearSelected">
 <option v-for="year in years" :key="year"> {{year}} </option>
</select>

<select v-model="selectedCat" >
 <option v-for="(item, index) in category" :item="item" 
 :key="index" :value="item.name"> {{ item.name }} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of how `tableData` is structured. Specifically how the category name is placed in it.

Comment: So my category dropdown is called from different get url which also has IDs and I have to get them from there. So again when I select "name" from the dropdown it filters only "name" rows which have other values like someVal, otherVal etc. If "name" doesnt exist for the selected year, do not show anything. tableData structure looks like so and it also includes categories:
    {"status":100,
    "result":[{
     "category":"Name",
     "year":2019,
     "username":"test",
     "otherValues":[
      {
      "someVal":30,
      "otherVal":20
      },]
    }
    ]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your tableData is an array of objects like this:

```
[
  { 
    "category":"Name", 
    "year":2019, 
    "username":"test", 
    "otherValues":[ 
      { 
        "someVal":30, 
        "otherVal":20 
      },
    ] 
  },
]
```

and you need to filter the items in the array based on the selected category name. Fortunately javascript can do this quite easily for us. There are several methods you can use to deal with arrays but in this case I think the `filter()` method should serve quite well. There is some more info about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Basically you need a new array that will display the selected data, or if nothing is selected, show the whole tableData array. This should be a computed property.

```
computed: {
  filteredTableData() {
    if (this.selectedCat !== null) {
      const filtered = this.tableData.filter(d => d.category === this.selectedCat)
      return filtered
    }
    return this.tableData
  },
}
```

This is assuming when you initialise `selectedCat` in data you set it to null. Therefore when someone selects a category it will meet the 'if' condition and our const 'filtered' will be a new array of all the 'tableData' elements that meet our condition. If nothing is selected the whole tableData array is returned.

When you are accessing the 'tableData' in your template, presumably with a `v-for="data in tableData"` you will now have to use `v-for="data in filteredTableData"`.